# Doxygen/C++: Global namespace in namespace list

Tags: c++, doxygen, global-namespace

Can I show the global namespace in the namespace list of the documentation generated with Doxygen? I have some functions which are `extern "C"`, they appear in the documentation of the header file that declares them, but not in the namespace list and it gives the impression that they are not really there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, this feature is still missing from Doxygen. One work-around that is not overly verbose is to use `@defgroup MyGlobals` and put the `extern "C"` functions in that group:

```
/*! @ingroup MyGlobals
 * @{ */

// ... functions

/*! @} */
```

This adds the functions in an entry called *MyGlobals* on the tab *Modules*.

[This blog entry](http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2009/09/doxygen-gotchas.html) presents a work-around using xrefs, but i personally find it too verbose.

Comment: Just to clarify, this will put the functions in an entry called "MyGlobals" on the tab "Modules" (not in "Namespaces").

Comment: Indeed, i should have mentioned that - added it.